# why do I get "200 Type set to I. (Net::FTPReplyError)"

Tags: ruby

**Note:** that I have both blocks of code (see below) in the same .rb file. The first time ftp.getbinaryfile() works then it throws the error.

**Note:** that `file` variable is a static path to the file used for debugging purposes only.

I have this code in `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]`

```
file = "/Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/E-mail Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf"

list = ftp.list('*')
list.each{|item| 

  counter=counter+1
  counter++
  ftp.getbinaryfile(file, where_to_save+File.basename(file)+counter.to_s, 1024)
  puts "downloaded - .each used"
}
```

then in the same .rb file I got this code

```
ftp.list('*') { |item| 
  puts "downloading using .list('*') {"
  counter++
  ftp.getbinaryfile(file, where_to_save+File.basename(file)+counter.to_s, 1024)

  puts "downloaded #{file}"
}
```

and that code throws me this error

```
Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:974:in `parse227': 200 Type set to I. (Net::FTPReplyError)
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:394:in `makepasv'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:406:in `transfercmd'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:487:in `block (2 levels) in retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:485:in `block in retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:484:in `retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:617:in `getbinaryfile'
```

ftp session is created by

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('ftp.***.***.net')
ftp.passive = false
ftp.debug_mode = true
ftp.login(ftp_username, ftp_password)
```

could someone explain why the second version works?

## UPDATE

Added ftp debugging log:

```
put: USER r.***
get: 331 Password required for r.***.
put: PASS ************
get: 230-Welcome to FTP
get: 230 User r.****logged in.
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Type set to I.
put: CWD /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/
get: 250 CWD command successful.
put: TYPE A
get: 200 Type set to A.
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (194,212,10,23,195,92).
put: LIST *
get: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
get: 226 Transfer complete.
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Type set to I.
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (194,212,10,23,195,93).
put: RETR /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/E-mail Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf
get: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
get: 226 Transfer complete.
downloaded - .each used
put: TYPE A
get: 200 Type set to A.
put: PASV
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,10,23,195,97).
put: LIST *
get: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
downloading using .list('*') {
put: TYPE I
get: 226 Transfer complete.
put: PASV
get: 200 Type set to I.
put: TYPE A
get: 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,10,23,195,98).
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Type set to A.
d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:974:in `parse227': 200 Type set to I. (Net::FTPReplyError)
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:394:in `makepasv'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:406:in `transfercmd'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:487:in `block (2 levels) in retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:485:in `block in retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:484:in `retrbinary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:617:in `getbinaryfile'
        from download2 - debugging.rb:41:in `block in <main>'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:518:in `block (3 levels) in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:515:in `loop'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:515:in `block (2 levels) in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:512:in `block in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:511:in `retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:760:in `list'
        from download2 - debugging.rb:38:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE2**

log if `ftp.passive = false` is used

```
downloading using .list('*') {
put: TYPE I
get: 226 Transfer complete.
put: PORT ***,***,20,102,235,136
get: 200 Type set to I.
put: RETR /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/Email Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf
get: 200 PORT command successful.
put: TYPE A
put: TYPE I
d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:211:in `write': An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (Errno::ECONNRESET)
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:211:in `write0'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:185:in `block in write'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:202:in `writing'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:184:in `write'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:283:in `putline'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:360:in `block in voidcmd'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:359:in `voidcmd'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:183:in `send_type_command'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:172:in `binary='
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:201:in `ensure in with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:201:in `with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:512:in `block in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:511:in `retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:760:in `list'
        from download2 - debugging.rb:39:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE3**

I tried to run the same code in ftp active mode few times and actually all files are downloaded but the script finishes with an error.

```
downloading using .list('*') {
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Type set to I.
put: PORT **,**,20,102,197,73
get: 200 PORT command successful.
put: RETR /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/E-mail Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf
get: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/E-mail Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf(
60911 bytes).
get: 226 Transfer complete.
put: TYPE A
get: 200 Type set to A.
downloaded /Filetrack/E-mail_Gateway/_Installer/GA/010_000_003_000/E-mail Gateway_10.0_Changes_PUBLIC.pdf
put: TYPE I
get: 200 Type set to I.
d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:1108:in `readline'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:289:in `getline'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:300:in `getmultiline'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:318:in `getresp'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:338:in `voidresp'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:526:in `block (2 levels) in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:199:in `with_binary'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:512:in `block in retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:511:in `retrlines'
        from d:/prog/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/ftp.rb:760:in `list'
        from download2 - debugging.rb:39:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What's the use of the variable `item` ?

Comment: @limekin: I used absolute value in variable file when debugging. Should be file .. updated my question.

Comment: I don't know why the second version works for you, but the code is wrong (in both cases). The results of `ftp.list` are similar to the ones you get with the command `ls -l`, so I don't think the FTP server you are interacting with will consider something like `-rw-r--r--  1 user user   13312 Mar  3 19:13 file.txt` as a valid filename.

Comment: you are right. I extract the name and check the whether it's file or directory. My point is that if I download inside list it fails. If I used .each it works. That's my observation even if I use absolute path to the file I am downloading.

Comment: Your example codes are very confusing - why do you have two loops when you are downloading same file.

Comment: @WandMaker: to show the difference when the same code `ftp.getbinaryfile(file, where_to_save+File.basename(file)+counter.to_s, 1024)` works and doesn't work.

Comment: @Radek Can you enable debug mode and share the results `ftp.debug_mode = true` ?  It seems my previous answer is not correct as pointed by TamehShlash in the comments of answer.  I have updated my answer - it does not give answer yet - but I put down my findings so far

Comment: Is the debug statements only for second case or includes first code as well?

Comment: @WandMaker: I added new log - basically the whole lot. I added two puts in the source code to show exactly what is happening. See `puts "downloaded - .each used"` in the first block of code and `puts "downloading using .list('*') {"` in the second block.

Comment: can you do `puts ENV["SOCKS_SERVER"]` inside the second code before you do `puts "downloading using .list('*') {"` and see what it prints? I think your server is behind a firewall and hence client is asked to open passive connection

Comment: I used `puts ENV["SOCKS_SERVER"]` in both blocks and in both cases it's empty.

Comment: Atlast, I think I found the root cause - I have updated my answer and also opened a bug with Ruby team

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Reason for `200 Type set to I. (Net::FTPReplyError)`

Your connection uses PASSIVE mode.  Since you have not shown the part of code you create `FTP` object, I will assume that you setting mode to `passive` explicitly.

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new('example.com')
ftp.passive = true
```

Based on the stack trace of exception, one can see that issue happens when the method `makepasv` issues `PASV` command, but instead of getting a response of `227 Entering Passive Mode (194,212,10,23,195,93).`,  it gets a response `200 Type set to I.`

Implementation of `makepasv` and `parse227` (Refer **Reference 1** & **Reference 2** later in the post) indicates that code specifically looks for return code of `227` and if that is not the case, it will throw an FTPError.

This is what is happening in the given scenario.

---

#### Why does `parse227` receive wrong response?

This can be attributed to the syntax shown below.
<sub>*This may very well be not so well understood behavior (as I myself discovered during the course answering to this post)*</sub>

```
ftp.list('*') { |item| 
  ftp.getbinaryfile(file, where_to_save+File.basename(file)+counter.to_s, 1024)
}
```

In the above code, a `LIST *` command is issued by `ftp.list('*')`.  Typical response for this command would like below:

```
put: LIST *
get: 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
get: 226 Transfer complete.
```

As can be seen, `LIST *` produces two lines of result.  This fact is crucial to understand the issue.

The block passed to `ftp.list('*')` downloads a binary file using `getbinaryfile` method.

`getbinaryfile` will typically issue below commands:

1. `TYPE I` to put the connection in image (binary) mode
2. `PASV`to enter passive mode
3. `RETR /path/of/file/to/download`

When the block executes for the first result of `ftp.list('*')`, and starts issuing commands related to `getbinaryfile`, at that point of time, only first line of response of `LIST *` has been read - the second line is yet to be read.  It is this second line that shows up as response to next command issued in the block.

Hence, when first command `TYPE I` is issued, the code reads the second line of `LIST *` as response (as evident in debug logs)

```
put: TYPE I
get: 226 Transfer complete.
```

When second command `PASV` is issued, the code reads the response of `TYPE I` (as evident from debug logs)

```
put: PASV
get: 200 Type set to I.
```

Implementation of `makepasv` is such that it expects that response to have response code of `227` (Refer line 394 and 973 in Reference 1 and Reference 2 respectively).  An exception `Net::FTPReplyError` was thrown gets thrown in this case as `parse227` was passed a response of `TYPE I` command.

**In summary, when using `passive` mode, it seems that it is not feasible to perform other FTP operations in the block given to `ftp.list('*')**

---

#### Why does `ftp.list('*').each` work?

In this case, the `ftp.list('*')` is invoked without a block, and hence it returns the Array of strings as output.  Using `each` on that array does not create the similar situation - and hence, there are no issues observed.

---

## Solution

It seems that author(s) of `FTP#list` expected the below two variants to work in equivalent manner:

```
ftp.list('*') { |f|  }  # block given to list
ftp.list('*').each { |f|  } # block given to enum returned by list
```

As per [official documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/FTP.html) of `list` API:

> #### list(*args) { |line| ... }
>
> Returns an array of file information in the
>   directory (the output is like `ls -l`). If a block is given, it
>   iterates through the listing.

If we look at the implementation of `list`, then, we see that when a block is given, each line read from `ftp.list('*')` is yielded to the block one by one.  When using passive mode, if the block tries to execute any other FTP commands, this causes the above mentioned.

```
754     def list(*args, &block) # :yield: line
755       cmd = "LIST"
756       args.each do |arg|
757         cmd = cmd + " " + arg.to_s
758       end
759       if block
760         retrlines(cmd, &block)
761       else
762         lines = []
763         retrlines(cmd) do |line|
764           lines << line
765         end
766         return lines
767       end
768     end
```

We can solve this problem by changing the implementation to become equivalent  to `ftp.list('*').each` variant by first collecting all lines from `LIST *` response into an array, and the passing that array to the block if a block was given.  We will still stay true to the API documentation.

```
def list(*args, &block) # :yield: line
  cmd = "LIST"
  args.each do |arg|
    cmd = cmd + " " + arg.to_s
  end

  # First lets fetch all the lines
  lines = []
  retrlines(cmd) do |line|
    lines << line
  end

  if block
    lines.each { |l| yield l }
  else
    return lines
  end
end
```

**I have reported a [bug in Ruby Bug Tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11454) suggesting above change in implementation of FTP#list method.**

---

**Reference 1** - Implementation of `makepasv`

```
391     # sends the appropriate command to enable a passive connection
392     def makepasv # :nodoc:
393       if @sock.peeraddr[0] == "AF_INET"
394         host, port = parse227(sendcmd("PASV"))
395       else
396         host, port = parse229(sendcmd("EPSV"))
397         #     host, port = parse228(sendcmd("LPSV"))
398       end
399       return host, port
400     end
```

**Reference 2** - Implementation of `parse227`

```
968     # handler for response code 227
969     # (Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2))
970     #
971     # Returns host and port.
972     def parse227(resp) # :nodoc:
973       if resp[0, 3] != "227"
974         raise FTPReplyError, resp
975       end
976       if m = /\((?<host>\d+(,\d+){3}),(?<port>\d+,\d+)\)/.match(resp)
977         return parse_pasv_ipv4_host(m["host"]), parse_pasv_port(m["port"])
978       else
979         raise FTPProtoError, resp
980       end
981     end
```

**Source code snippets were taken from [`ftp.rb`.](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/net/ftp.rb?v=2.0.0-p481)**

**UPDATE: 13 Sep, 2015**
[The proposed change](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11454) has been [accepted](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/d5d6b149df3d2d565859599334327e378e5b2a84) by Ruby core team for this issue.

Comment: I have that set. I have both blocks in the came .rb file. I updated my question to make it more visible.

Comment: Can you try the way I suggested now and tell me if you see error?

Comment: `ftp.binary(true)` gives me error `download2.rb:65:in '<main>': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`. So I used `ftp.binary = true` and it did not help.

Comment: @Radek - I checked the code that you say you are using, it seems to work fine.  See example I posted.   Can you try the same and let me know whether it works for you?  If yes, then, replace FTP server details with your server and try again

Comment: I am connecting to our company FTP - Microsoft FTP Service.

Comment: using `ftp.nlst('atac-2005*').each { block }` is NOT the same as using `ftp.list('*') { block }`, which is the case in the question.

Comment: @TamerShlash: exactly, I realized that and I've been testing it. Could you tell me what the difference is? If I use `ftp.list('*').each` instead of `ftp.list('*') ` then it works. Maybe create your own answer.

Comment: @Radek I'm looking into the issue in the question currently. But using `ftp.list('*').each` is exactly the same as using `list = ftp.list('*') ; list.each`. I'll explain further if I conclude to any explanation and write an answer.

Comment: @TamerShlash  I saw the difference, but I was still thinking issue is at `getbinaryfile` level -  the `list` output is like output of `ls -l` command and one has to take file name out of it, however `nlst` gives the file name as string

Comment: @Radek I  have installed `Filezilla` FTP server on windows, and tried the code, did not get the same error as you reported.

Comment: @WandMaker: the issue is that I get error in the second block. Now if I use `.each` it works ok. I am not a ruby guru to see the difference / explanation.

Comment: @WandMaker: don't use nlst but list and then absolute path to the file. I know it doesn't make much sense to download the same file few times but that's how I tested it. Please use list without .each. If i works for you then I'll except your answers and maybe it's about our company FTP server.

Comment: @Radek I get `550 File not found (Net::FTPPermError)` error, not the error what you indicated if I use `list` without `.each`.  The reason for that is obvious though - the output of `list` is an Array of string where each string looks like `"-r--r--r-- 1 ftp ftp        1286663 Jul 26  2013 bcprov-jdk16-1.45-sources.jar"`   -   You can try with wrong code but that is of no use.

Comment: @WandMaker: that's why I suggested that you use absolute path or you extract file name from the list.

Comment: I updated my question. Note that I have static path to a file in variable `file` which I am using in `ftp.getbinaryfile`. That's why I use counter at all. The code is only for debugging the issue. Of course I would download using different code.

Comment: I have updated the answer - as to why the ftp client switches to text mode - that is how that `list` behaves if you pass it a block - I don't think you can download file in that way of API call

Comment: The answer still suffers two dangerous problems: 1) you are looking at `ftp.rb` in the latest version, not the ruby 2.0.0p481 vesrion. 2) if you look at the `getbinaryfile` you'll figure out that it calls `retrbinary` which sets the mode to binary again, so your explanation is totally wrong and irrelevant.

Comment: @TamerShlash I did some more reading based on your points - updated the answer - thats the best I can do for now

Comment: I added `Update2` and code how I create ftp connection. You are right I am using passive type of connection.

Comment: @radek I see a new exception in your update 2,  any idea what is that about?

Comment: @Wand: not sure. I tried only once in active mode before. But now I ran the same code few more times and actually ALL files were downloaded but the script finishes with UPDATE3 error.

Comment: @Radek  I see.  I assume that you raised this query out of curiosity.  The first syntax with `.each` and in `passive` mode, works fine - do you have any issue in using that syntax?  Or is there any specific reason to use 2nd syntax?

Comment: well, I am not a programing guru so I search google copy and paste. I did that and got the code without .each. Then got the issue, found solution and posted question. I have no issue with .each. Actually I guess I will rewrite the code to use .nlst instead. Thank you for your time and great debugging skills :-)

Comment: @Radek - Welcome, I am no good at debugging as can be seen from number of revisions this answer went through :-)   I learned something new in the process and I am happy about that

Comment: I'd say that's the read debugging you showed us ..."process of getting to the root cause" ...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it disabling "This server is sitting behind a router/firewall" function insde Server Advanced.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylPQR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).